# Bootstrap selectpicker - All options have a tick

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having a strange problem with bootstrap select option. I want to show the tick when the option is selected but the problem is that all the options have the tick "Ok" showed even if it is not clicked.

this is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        style : 'btn-info',
        size : 4,
        iconBase: 'glyphicon',
        tickIcon: 'glyphicon-ok'
    });     
});     

<div class="col-md-6" style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
        <span style="width:50%;" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Are you ok?</span> 
        <select class="selectpicker" name="object_example" >
            <option value="1">True</option>                                     
            <option value="2">False</option>
        </select>   
    </div>
</div>
```

The tick is **always** there..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was in `bootstrap-select.js` and `bootstrap-select.css` files.
I re-download them from [Here](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and now it works.

I also needed to change the class name to:

```
class="selectpicker show-tick form-control"
```